# Transitioning IoT Agent from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Hello Overstock community! I've recently set up an IoT Agent Orion architecture and have it running on AWS. However, I want to enhance security by switching from HTTP to HTTPS. Could anyone guide me through the process of implementing HTTPS for my IoT Agent?

implementing HTTPS for my IoT Agent on EC2